# SELECT 4 latest rows from Oracle table with join

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, rownum

I'm quite new to Oracle so I'm not totally familiar with the `ROWNUM` statement. I'm trying to get the latest 4 articles from my table. I'm getting 4 results but they are 2012 articles even though my date ordering is set to `DESC`. Any help would be great.

Oracle query:

```
SELECT bt.article_id, ba.* 
FROM articles_types bt 
LEFT JOIN blog_articles ba 
ON ba.article_id = bt.article_id 
WHERE ROWNUM < 5 
ORDER BY Published DESC
```

Comment: In traditional Oracle SQL statements, the Where clause referring to Rownum gets parsed first, and only THEN the Order By is parsed, which leads to wrong results. It's a nice example of syntax that looks OK, and that would be parsed correctly if a more human would parse it, but the computer performs all Where clauses first, ignoring pseudo-column functions that actually depend on the output itself (as Order By changes the output). You must also know that any statement without Order By has not got any logic ordering, at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but order the result before rownum limit:

```
select t.* from
(
SELECT * 
FROM articles_types bt 
LEFT JOIN blog_articles ba 
ON ba.article_id = bt.article_id 
ORDER BY Published DESC
) T
WHERE ROWNUM <= 4
```

This worked, the issue was a duplicate column name

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned I have tried that and I just get the following error in oracle developer: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8

Comment: @huddds - you're getting `article_id` from both tables; you should specify the columns you want from `ba` rather than using `*` (which is generally a good idea anyway), and leave out the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make a note of that, still getting to grips with oracle

Answer (score 2):

The `where` clause is evaluated before the `order by` clause. So what's happening here is that you're selecting the first four rows returned by the database (in completely arbitrary order), and then sorting them in descending order of `Published`.

One solution could be to move the `where` clause to an outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT    bt.article_id, ba.* 
        FROM      articles_types bt 
        LEFT JOIN blog_articles ba ON ba.article_id = bt.article_id 
        ORDER BY Published DESC)
WHERE  ROWNUM < 5
```

Alternative, In Oracle 12c, you can (finally!) use a `fetch first` clause:

```
SELECT      bt.article_id, ba.* 
FROM        articles_types bt 
LEFT JOIN   blog_articles ba ON ba.article_id = bt.article_id 
ORDER BY    Published DESC
FETCH FIRST 4 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: FETCH FIRST is very convenient!

Answer (score 1):

The `rownum` function is applied before `order by`, so it selects the first 4 unordered records that it finds.

To achieve the result you are looking for with `rownum` you will have to essentially turn this query into a subquery, and apply `rownum` in the outer query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT 
    bt.article_id, ba.* 
FROM 
    articles_types bt 
LEFT JOIN 
    blog_articles ba 
ON 
    ba.article_id = bt.article_id 
ORDER BY 
    Published DESC)
WHERE rownum < 5
```

Comment: I've tried this and get the following error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8

Comment: Both of your tables appear to have a column named "article_id", and you are pulling them both in with the subquery, hence the ambiguity. You could either list out all the columns in the ba table that you want (minus article_id), or just not select the bt.article_id column in the subquery